# Google Play Services Nearby Messages authorization dialog not fully shown

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

When displaying the authorization dialog for Nearby Messages (Play Services SDK 7.8) on low res/small screen devices, the dialog doesn't display all of the options to select. It only shows the "Reject" option but the "Allow" is not displayed:

[image]

Is there a way to set this dialog programatically to better fit smaller screens?

Comment: This is a bug of Play Services then. The user still has an option to press back though :P

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I have a feeling that the end user won't be bothered with this. It will just confuse them.

Comment: I guess there is nothing you can do but wait till Google releases a new version of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I have notified the Nearby team at Google and will update this space when this is fixed